# how to validate both input fields when one updates

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to validate both input fields when one changes its value. This is required because otherwise the validation between those two fields would not work properly.

I created an example to reproduce the problem, the html code should be self explanatory

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
          <v-text-field
              :value="values[0]"
              :rules="firstRules"
              @input="setFirstValue"
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
              :value="values[1]"
              :rules="secondRules"
              @input="setSecondValue"
            ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

It is important to note that a `v-model` is not possible because this component takes in the values as a `prop` and passes the updated values back to the parent via emitting update events.

The vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      values: [5345, 11],
      firstRules: [true],
      secondRules: [true]
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.setFirstValue(this.values[0])
    this.setSecondValue(this.values[1])
  },
  computed: {
    firstValidation: function () {
      return [value => value.length < this.values[1].length || "Must have less characters than second value"]
    },
    secondValidation: function () {
      return [value => value.length > this.values[0].length || "Must have more characters than first value"]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFirstValue: function (newValue) {
      this.values[0] = newValue
      this.firstRules = this.validateValue(this.values[0], this.firstValidation)
      this.secondRules = this.validateValue(this.values[1], this.secondValidation)
    },
    setSecondValue: function (newValue) {
      this.values[1] = newValue
      this.secondRules = this.validateValue(this.values[1], this.secondValidation)
      this.firstRules = this.validateValue(this.values[0], this.firstValidation)
    },
    validateValue: function (value, rules) {
      for (const rule of rules) {
          const result = rule(value)

          if (typeof result === 'string') {
            return [result]
          }
      }

      return [true]
    }
  }
})
```

On "start" the rules return a valid state but I want to validate both fields when loading the component (created hook?) to update this state immediately.

I have to put the validation rules to the computed properties because they have to access the current values. Otherwise they would validate old values.

Each input event will validate both fields and updates the rules state.

I created an example to play around here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeKVME?editors=1010

Unfortunately two problems come up:

- The fields are not validated directly at the beginning
- when changing one input field to a valid state the rules will still return an error message

How can I setup a validation for both fields when one field updates?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems like you're overthinking things.

By default, a vuetify input's validation logic only triggers when the value bound to that input changes. In order to trigger the validation for the other input, you can wrap both inputs in a `v-form` component and give it a `ref` attribute. That way, you'll have access to that component's `validate` method, which will trigger the validation logic for any inputs inside the form.

The template would look something like this:

```
<v-form ref="form">
  <v-text .../>
  <v-text .../>
</v-form>
```

And to trigger the validation in your script:

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.form.validate();
}
```

The above will validate the form when the component is mounted, but you'll also need to trigger the validation for both inputs whenever either input's value changes. For this, you can add a watcher to `values`. However, you'll need to call the form's `validate` method after Vue has updated the DOM to reflect the change in `values`.

To do this, either wrap the call in a [`this.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) call:

```
watch: {
  values() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.form.validate();
    });
  }
}
```

Or use an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `await this.$nextTick`:

```
watch: {
  async values() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.$refs.form.validate();
  }
}
```

So now validation will trigger for both inputs when the component is initialized and whenever either value changes. However, if you prefer to keep the validation call in one spot instead of in both the `mounted` hook and the `values` watcher, you can make the watcher `immediate` and get rid of the call in the `mounted` hook.

So here's the final example:

```
watch: {
  immediate: true,
  async handler() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    this.$refs.form.validate();
  }
}
```

---

So now the validation logic is triggering when it would be expected to, but there is still one issue with your validation logic. When your component initializes, the `values` data property is set to an array of `Number` type values, which don't have a `length` property. So if, for example, you changed just the first input to `"5"` and the second input was still `11`, then `(11).length` is `undefined` and `"5".length < undefined` is `false`.

Anyways, you'll need to change the values you're comparing to strings before comparing their lengths. Something like this:

```
value => (value + '').length < (this.values[1] + '').length
```

---

Finally, because you are able to dynamically call `validate` on the form, there's an opportunity to reduce much of the complexity of your component.

Here's a simplified version:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      values: [5345, 11]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rules() {
      const valid = (this.values[0] + '').length < (this.values[1] + '').length;
      return {
        first: [() => valid || "Must have less characters than second value"], 
        second: [() => valid || "Must have more characters than first value"]
      };
    }
  },
  watch: {
    values: {
      immediate: true,
      async handler() {
        await this.$nextTick();
        this.$refs.form.validate();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form ref="form">
      <v-text-field v-model="values[0]" :rules="rules.first"></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field v-model="values[1]" :rules="rules.second"></v-text-field>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this suffer the problem that if there were other input fields on the form that the user had not yet entered data into, the validation on these fields would also be triggered; resulting in a less than ideal user experience. Is there any way to trigger validation just on particular fields rather then the whole form?

Comment: @DamianHelme, yeah but that functionality is baked into vuetify. But looks like they're planning to implement a feature request to add the ability to validate single inputs within a form. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8698

Comment: It looks like it's there already. I've just looked in the source code and there's a .validate() function in the Validatable mixin - which is marked as 'public' - does that mean it's OK to use?. I've just tried adding a ref to text field 1, putting a watcher on text field 2 which calls this.$refs.textFiel1.validate(). Seems to work OK. Anything I've missed? Have to admit to being a Veutify neophyte.

Comment: Yeah I'll admit to not being well-versed on Vuetify either. I'd go read through the documentation to see what they suggest. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms Looks like you might want to use `vee-validate`

Comment: Thank you for showing your thinking proccess along your solution. For me the key part was using `$nextTick()` inside the watcher.  Without using it, my validations just got crazy (I guess there was a deterministic reason but didn't stop to find what).

Comment: This really helped me, when validation passwords, changing the password after filling the password confirmation field was creating a validation gap.

Comment: @DamianHelme are you using this on Vue 3 or Vue 2? Because, I am trying to call the `$refs.field.validate()`, but it does not seem to work. I am using version 2.6.12 of Vue and 2.5.6 of Vuetify.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot call `this.$refs.form.validate();` because it is in a parent component, what you can do is put a ref attribute on your v-text-field.

```
<v-text-field ref="textFieldRef"></v-text-field>
```

And call it's validate fonction where you want

```
this.$refs.textFieldRef.validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to do like below to make it work.

```
watch: {
    rangeAmuount: {
      async handler() {
        await this.$nextTick()
        if (this.$refs.form) (this.$refs.form as any).validate()
      },
      deep: true,
    },
}
```

PS: I'm using typescript on Vue2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).